# CRUD PHP Não atualiza e nem dá erro

Tags: php, mysql, formulário, sql-update, crud

Estou tendo problemas quando tento executar um UPDATE no meu sistema em PHP + MySQL.

Tenho o código do arquivo editar:

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

// resgata os valores do formulario
$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome']: null;
$nascimento = isset($_POST['nascimento']) ? $_POST['nascimento']: null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email']: null;
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha']: null;
$seg_senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Validação para evitar dados vazios
if (empty($nome) || empty($nascimento) || empty($email) || empty($senha)) {
    echo 'Volte e preencha todos os campos.';
    exit;
}

// Atualiza o banco
$pdo = db_connect();
$sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET nome = :nome, nasc = :nasc, email = :email, senha = :senha WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
$stmt->bindParam(':nasc', $nascimento);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':senha', $seg_senha);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

if ($stmt->execute()){
    header('Location: ../index1.php');
}else{
    echo 'Erro ao atualizar usuario.';
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Agora o arquivo com formulário para edição de usuário:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';

// Pega o id da URL
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id']: null;

// Valida o id
if (empty($id)) {
    echo 'ID para alteração nao definido';
    exit;
}

// Busca os dados do usuario a ser editado
$pdo = db_connect();
$sql = "SELECT nome, nasc, email, senha FROM usuarios WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();

$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Se o método fetch() não retornar um array, significa que o ID não corresponde a um usuário válido
if(!is_array($user)){
    echo 'Nenhum usuario encontrado.';
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<!-- ==================== TABLE INICIO - BOOTSTRAP ==================== -->
<div class="panel panel-success " style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 20px">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <center>
                <b>EDITAR USUARIO</b>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <form method="POST" action="core/editar.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                     <input type="hidden" value="" name="id" class="form-control" id="exampleInputId1"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                     <input type="text" value="<?php echo $user['nome'] ?>" name="nome" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Nome"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="label label-default">Data de nascimento</span>
                    <input type="date" value="<?php echo $user['nasc'] ?>" data-date="" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY" class="form-control" for="nasc" name="nascimento">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-MAIL</label>
                    <input type="email" value="<?php echo $user['email'] ?>" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                    <input type="password" value="<?php echo $user['senha'] ?>" name="senha" class="form-control" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Finalizar edição</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- ==================== TABLE INICIO - BOOTSTRAP ==================== -->
</body>
</html>
```

Quando altero os campos e clico no botão ele não retorna erro algum, somente retorna para a página `index1.php`, como mandei no `header`. Mas no banco o campo "alterado" continua do mesmo jeito, como se não tivesse feito alteração alguma.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar? Grato!

Comment: Onde é que você está inicializando a variável `$id` na parte que faz o UPDATE?

Comment: no primeiro código que você postou, faz um echo na variável $sql e vê o que ela retorna. só pra ter certeza que ela está recebendo as variáveis de forma correta.

Comment: Coloquei o comando para captura do id... Mas continua do mesmo jeito :/

Fiz um echo na variavel $sql como disse, e retornou isso aqui:

UPDATE usuarios SET nome = :nome, nasc = :nasc, email = :email, senha = :senha WHERE id = :id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neste bloco você vincula a variável `$id` para usar no `WHERE`

```
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
$stmt->bindParam(':nasc', $nascimento);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':senha', $seg_senha);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
```

Porém, na hora da captura, você está pegando todos os campos, menos o `$id`:

```
// resgata os valores do formulario
$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome']: null;
$nascimento = isset($_POST['nascimento']) ? $_POST['nascimento']: null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email']: null;
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha']: null;
$seg_senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Além disso, precisa por o `value` no formulário:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user['id']; ?>" name="id" class="form....
                             ^^  falta algo assim  ^^
```

Resolvendo estas coisas, tem que pensar em uma maneira de um usuário malicioso não trocar manualmente o ID e alterar uma conta que não tenha acesso.

Se o usuário só pode alterar os próprios dados, pode remover o campo escondido e usar apenas o ID de quem está logado, mas de qualquer forma, provavelmente precisa validar os campos com mais cuidado.

Comment: Coloquei o comando para captura do id... Mas continua do mesmo jeito :/

Comment: Nao é só capturar, precisa por ele no form, testar, e ver se está sendo enviado. Por exemplo, depois das alterações mencionadas, precisa olhar o source do formulário no navegador e ver se foi o ID certo no form.

Comment: Quando inseri o comando de captura do do id, inseri de forma errada, escrevi $POST ao invés de $_POST... Digitei sem o underline. Agora resolveu o problema. No inicio o problema era mesmo a falta da captura do id.
Obrigado pela ajuda @Bacco

Comment: @Gabriel estamos aqui pra isso, que bom que resolveu.